# Python doesn't plot the graph

Tags: python

i have a little problem with matplotlib and python. So my problem is the line don't appear in the plot. I am trying to make a graph of a custom function. My code is here bellow:

```
import scipy
from numpy import arange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def integral_function(x, a, b, c): # defines the function
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c
for r in arange(0,5,0.01): # defines the range and step
    x = r
y =scipy.integrate.quad(integral_function, 0, x, args=(2,3,4))[0] # computes the integral for the first list of constants
y1 = scipy.integrate.quad(integral_function, 0, x, args=(2,1,1))[0] # computes the integral for the second list of constants
plt.plot(r, y) # plots the results of the first list of constants
plt.plot(r, y1) # plots the results of the  second list of constants
plt.xlabel("r values")
plt.ylabel("values of integration")
plt.legend(["for a,b,c = 2,3,4","for a,b,c = 2,1,1"])
plt.title("integration of ax^2 + bx + c")
plt.show()
```

Everytime that i run the code the graph appears without the lines. Please could someone can help me ? Thank you for the attention :)

Comment: What are you trying to do when assigning `x` over and over in a loop? `x = r`?

Comment: x is just one point here. (a `for` shouldn't happen in numpy code). just try `x = arange(0,5,0.01)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to plot a point using `plot()` function. You can either use `scatter()` function to draw the point or pass a color and dot sign to `plot()` function.

```
import scipy
from numpy import arange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def integral_function(x, a, b, c): # defines the function
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c

for r in arange(0,5,0.01): # defines the range and step
    x = r
    y =scipy.integrate.quad(integral_function, 0, x, args=(2,3,4))[0] # computes the integral for the first list of constants
    y1 = scipy.integrate.quad(integral_function, 0, x, args=(2,1,1))[0] # computes the integral for the second list of constants
    plt.plot(r, y,'b.') # plots the results of the first list of constants
    plt.plot(r, y1,'r.') # plots the results of the  second list of constants
plt.xlabel("r values")
plt.ylabel("values of integration")
plt.legend(["for a,b,c = 2,3,4","for a,b,c = 2,1,1"])
plt.title("integration of ax^2 + bx + c")
plt.show()
```

The output will be :

[image]

Is there a better way to draw this plot? Absolutely! It's recommended to calculate all values before plotting, then plotting all values at once.

```
import scipy
from numpy import arange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def integral_function(x, a, b, c): # defines the function
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c
y = []
y1 = []
for r in arange(0,5,0.01): # defines the range and step
    x = r
    y.append(scipy.integrate.quad(integral_function, 0, x, args=(2,3,4))[0]) # computes the integral for the first list of constants
    y1.append(scipy.integrate.quad(integral_function, 0, x, args=(2,1,1))[0]) # computes the integral for the second list of constants

    
r = arange(0,5,0.01)
plt.plot(r, y,'b')
plt.plot(r, y1,'r')
plt.xlabel("r values")
plt.ylabel("values of integration")
plt.legend(["for a,b,c = 2,3,4","for a,b,c = 2,1,1"])
plt.title("integration of ax^2 + bx + c")
plt.show()
```

And here is the output of recommended method :

[image]